# tree Full Path Prefix not displayed

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, monterey, open-source

I have installed `tree` using `homebrew`, however it isn't behaving as expected.  I have the following to list recursive files, but I want the full path for each file to be displayed.  Unfortunately it's showing the navigation vertical and horizontal characters instead.

`tree -f -L 2`

This is what the `man page` shows:

`-f     Prints the full path prefix for each file.`

I'm using macOS 12.3 Monterey and wonder is the manual page wrong?  This is what I was expecting, because it says **full path**:

```
$ pwd
/Users/username
$ <tree command>
~/alpha/file1.txt
~/alpha/file2.txt
~/alpha/subalpha/file3.txt
~/alpha/subalpha/file4.txt
~/bravo/file5.txt
~/bravo/file6.txt
~/bravo/subalpha/file6.txt
...
```

Comment: Why not use `find . -d 3` in place of `<tree command>`?

Comment: No reason.  I just navigate towards `tree` for recursive filesystem lists like this.  Your syntax also doesn't have full `path` which is hugely useful.  Just checked the man page and I can't see an option of full `path` as output, only from `.`.  Can you find it?

Comment: I suppose I should have suggested `find ~ -d 3`, which does output the full path.

Comment: `find $(pwd) -d 2` restricts the scope to the only parent directory I want displayed.  Works.

Comment: If you want the depth shown in your example, then you would need to enter `-d 3`. Also, `$(pwd)` needs double quotes. So instead of `find $(pwd) -d 2`, you should use `find "$(pwd)" -d 3`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Tried it out.  The one I posted gives me the full list.  The files I want presented are one directory deep from `pwd`.  Your version takes me into only subdirectories that don't have scripts but data.  Any way of listing all single to two directories deep?  Part of this is just getting to know the syntax of possibilities.  My real application is a single layer deep.

Comment: Ah ok.  Again, this is about my specific application, but I did post for subdirs as well.  Nicely done.

Comment: I have been interpreting your example incorrectly. You might consider editing your question to further clarify what you are looking for. The double quotes are needed for cases where `$(pwd)` contains a space character. Since the output shown in the example given in your question does not find directories, a `-type f` could be added. Also, `-d 3` should have been `-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3`. This would make the command `find "$(pwd)" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -type f`. If you only need files ending in `.txt`, then use `find "$(pwd)" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.txt"`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Ya I use `find` in other instances with `-name`. But the goal of how it was posted was to consider a controlled depth recursive as well.  All good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems it's showing the relative path, in this case, current directory ".", specifying the full path as an option works though.

Don't know if that's expected behavior or not

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar && touch /tmp/foo/bar/dump && cd /tmp/foo
 
$ tree -f
.
└── ./bar
    └── ./bar/dump

$ tree -f $(pwd)
/tmp/foo
└── /tmp/foo/bar
    └── /tmp/foo/bar/dump
```

Comment: OK, using `.` means relative path, not full path.  I will modify the question with expectations.

Comment: Oh hey that works.  I didn't pick up on your second example.  Nicely done.